# Any idea about why my background color is not workin

Tags: javascript, html

I did a simple js exercise in my html, the thing is, it just will pop up a new div when my radial input were pressed,
so anytime my radial input(any of those 3) got pressed a pop up div will slide down(till now, i just did it with my first radial input, but as it not working, i wont apply anything to the left 3)

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");


let NewW = document.querySelector(".Appear");



function NewWindow(){

//--*------------HERE LIE THE PROBLEM---------------*-----    
         NewW.style.backgroundColor = "red";
         NewW.style.width = "100%";
         NewW.style.display = "inline-block";

//--*-----------------------------------------------*---
    (function moveDown() {
        var top = parseInt(NewW.style.marginTop); // get the top margin
                                                 // we'll be using this to
                                                 // push the div down

        if (!top) {
            top = 0; // if the margin is undefined, default it to zero
        }

        top += 20; // add 20 pixels to the current margin
        
        NewW.style.marginTop = top + 'px'; // push div down
        
        if (top < 100) {
            // If it's not yet 200 pixels then call this function
            // again in another 100 milliseconds (100 ms gives us
            // roughly 10 fps which should be good enough):
            setTimeout(moveDown,100);
        }


        //from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606932/javascript-slide-element
        //** slebetman answer


        //I just add up this one to close my div when clicked again
        if(top > 100)
        {
            NewW.style.marginTop = 0 + 'px';//Go back in plache whe clicke again
            NewW.style.display = "none";
        }
    })();
    
    

}



function Equilate(l1,l2,l3){ //ignore here, im trying to solve the up problem first.
    return  l1*l2*l3;
}


EquiConst.addEventListener("click",NewWindow);
```

```html
<div class="outer_content">
    <form>  
        <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>  
        <input id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral"> Equilateral<br>  
        <div class="Appear" id="WindowOut" ></div>
        <input id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>  
        <input id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>   
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `marginTop` to `height`. Using the margin pushes the div upward

Comment: OOh thanks, i was sooo focus on this that i completely forgot about the height. Work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add CSS attribute height for your styles. For example

```
NewW.style.backgroundColor = "red";
NewW.style.width = "100%";
NewW.style.display = "inline-block";
NewW.style.height = "200px";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the element isn't growing at all. Initially it's having a `height` of 0, in which case, no matter how much width or margin you set, it's going to remain invisible. When you increase the `margin` to expand it, it will add the space between the two inputs but the element itself isn't growing as the `margin` exists *outside* the element.

if you set the `height` or `padding` (which takes space *inside* the element) that will work as you expect. I use `paddingTop` in the example.

note that in both of the examples below, I have commented out the link tag to the css file and the script tag for the js file to make it work here. The html is otherwise untouched.

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");

let NewW = document.querySelector(".Appear");

function NewWindow() {

  //--*------------HERE LIE THE PROBLEM---------------*-----    
  NewW.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  NewW.style.width = "100%";
  NewW.style.display = "inline-block";

  //--*-----------------------------------------------*---
  (function moveDown() {
    var top = parseInt(NewW.style.paddingTop); // get the top margin
    // we'll be using this to
    // push the div down

    if (!top) {
      top = 0; // if the margin is undefined, default it to zero
    }

    top += 20; // add 20 pixels to the current margin

    NewW.style.paddingTop = top + 'px'; // push div down

    if (top < 100) {
      // If it's not yet 200 pixels then call this function
      // again in another 100 milliseconds (100 ms gives us
      // roughly 10 fps which should be good enough):
      setTimeout(moveDown, 100);
    }


    //from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606932/javascript-slide-element
    //** slebetman answer


    //I just add up this one to close my div when clicked again
    if (top > 100) {
      NewW.style.paddingTop = 0 + 'px'; //Go back in plache whe clicke again
      NewW.style.display = "none";
    }
  })();
}

function Equilate(l1, l2, l3) { //ignore here, im trying to solve the up problem first.
  return l1 * l2 * l3;
}

EquiConst.addEventListener("click", NewWindow);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Training">
        <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
        <title>Training</title><!--Practice-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
        <!--Estou colocando em ingles, mas vou traduzindo nos comentarios
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile.css">
    <script src="JsExc3.js" defer></script> -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="outer_content">
            <form>  
                <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>  
                <input id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral"> Equilateral<br>  
                <div class="Appear" id="WindowOut" ></div>
                <input id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>  
                <input id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>   
              </form>
        </div>
       
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Alternative Answer (CSS & JavaScript approach)**

I would like to suggest a better approach to do the same thing. that is, using CSS.

For the element with the `.Appear` class, I'm setting the background color to red and adding the CSS `transition` property for the padding set to animate in 0.5 seconds. After setting that, if you change padding by adding the css clas `.show` to it, it will transition the `padding` from 0 to 100px within 0.5 seconds.

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");
let NewW = document.querySelector(".Appear");

var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

function handleChange(e) {
  if(e.target.value === 'equilateral') {
    NewW.classList.add("drop");
  } else {
    NewW.classList.remove("drop");
  }
}

// trigger handler with all radio buttons
radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
    radioButton.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
});
```

```css
.Appear {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: padding 0.5s;
}
.Appear.drop {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Training">
        <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
        <title>Training</title><!--Practice-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                       <!--Estou colocando em ingles, mas vou traduzindo nos comentarios
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile.css">
    <script src="JsExc3.js" defer></script> -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="outer_content">
            <form>  
                <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>  
                <input id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral"> Equilateral<br>  
                <div class="Appear"></div>
                <input id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>  
                <input id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>   
              </form>
        </div>
       
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Alternative Answer (JS only approach)**
If you are looking for a way to animate using JS only, [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is worth trying. According to the MDN article:

> The frequency of calls to the callback function will generally match
> the display refresh rate. The most common refresh rate is 60hz, (60
> cycles/frames per second), though 75hz, 120hz, and 144hz are also
> widely used. requestAnimationFrame() calls are paused in most browsers
> when running in background tabs or hidden s, in order to
> improve performance and battery life.

This means the JS runtime will determine the number of times the animation code gets executed based on the state and performance of the browser it's running on, rather than fixed intervals.

Note that I'm using the `height` property in this example.

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");
let NewW = document.querySelector(".Appear");

let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

// to store timestamp each time Animate is invoked
let start = null;
// in milliseconds, so for 0.5 seconds, it's 0.5s * 1000 = 500ms
const animation_length = 500;

// the timestamp will be passed in by the requestAnimationFrameMethod 
function Animate(timestamp) {
  // set start if not already set
  if (!start) start = timestamp;

  // check progress for current frame
  let time_elapsed = timestamp - start;

  // change the animatino based on progress
  NewW.style.height = (time_elapsed / animation_length * 100) + 'px';

  if (time_elapsed < animation_length) {
    // animation not complete, continue animation with this recursive call
    requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
  } else {
    // end of animation, reset start for the next time
    start = null;
  }
}

// trigger handler with all radio buttons
radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
  radioButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if(e.target.value == 'equilateral') {
      requestAnimationFrame(Animate);  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="Training">
  <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
  <title>Training</title>
  <!--Practice-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Estou colocando em ingles, mas vou traduzindo nos comentarios
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile.css">
    <script src="JsExc3.js" defer></script> -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer_content">
    <form>
      <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>
      <input id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral"> Equilateral<br>
      <div class="Appear" id="WindowOut"></div>
      <input id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>
      <input id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: beautiful approach, i didnt use css' cause initially my goal was training for js only, thats why i didnt take a look on how to do this using css. Good solving btw. It help me a lot on some  using ways for event handlers.

Comment: @Sung-99 I've added a JavaScript example that runs smoother, functions pretty much the same as the CSS example I provided.