# Simple question about HTML content and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

It happens a lot with me, i set on my HTML code on a specific content display: none, not to show the inner content (child node), unless someone click on it, so, in my css i create another class, to display:block just to when someone clik on my content, I toggle or add this class and then, child node be showed, but it is not working, so i put !important on my css class and it work perfeclty fine, i would like to understand why.

Here is my HTML code, where class 'appear' is such a class that i would like not to show, unless someone click on the radio.

Here is my css code, where on .appear .drop, when someone clik on my radio, i would like to show my class 'appear' and change the display:none to block, but it work ONLY when i typed !important(which already has been added)

Here my js code.

I'm just looking for a explantion about it, I am newbie.

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");


let NewW = document.querySelectorAll(".Appear");



var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');


//use code from Azoof Ahmed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77956842/any-idea-about-why-my-background-color-is-not-workin/77957267#77957267
//but added just a simple feature on work in all my 3 elements
function handleChange(e) {
  if(e.target.value === 'equilateral') {
    NewW[0].classList.add("drop");
   
  } else {
    NewW[0].classList.remove("drop");
  }

  if(e.target.value === 'rectangle') {
    NewW[1].classList.add("drop");
  } else {
    NewW[1].classList.remove("drop");
  }               
  
  if(e.target.value === 'isosceles') {
    NewW[2].classList.add("drop");
  } else {
    NewW[2].classList.remove("drop");
  }
}

// trigger handler with all radio buttons
radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
    
        radioButton.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
    
    
});


//append child to my div appear for put some data in there

let sideEqui = document.createElement("input")
let child1 = NewW[0].appendChild(sideEqui);
```

```css
.Appear {
    width: 100%;
    
    transition: padding 0.5s;
  }
  .Appear.drop {
    display: block !important;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer_content">
  <form>  
    <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>  
    <input class="App" id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral">Equilateral<br>  
    <div class="Appear" style="display: none;"></div>
    <input class="App" id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>  
    <div class="Appear"></div>
    <input class="App" id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>
    <div class="Appear" ></div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `display: none` directly in the element style will override the style from the CSS file. (Unless you use `!important`. That's usually a sign that you're doing something wrong.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order

Comment: i was look for a content to read about it to understand better about this rules and standards on html, thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity 

Comment: Mozilla MDN should assist... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important

Comment: just use important which has higher priority than style (the biggest one)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting display none and a class of Appear on your div elements in the html, just include a class for Hidden on your elements. Then in your Javascript you can remove or add back that class of Hidden. It simplifies your code and removes any need for !important.

Here is a stripped down version of your code with these changes.

```js
let NewW = document.querySelectorAll(".Hidden")
let radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')

radioButtons.forEach( function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
} )

function handleChange( event ) {
  // event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove( "Hidden" )
  if( event.target.value == "equilateral" ) {
    NewW[0].classList.remove( "Hidden" )
  }
  else NewW[0].classList.add( "Hidden" )

  if( event.target.value == "rectangle" ) {
    NewW[1].classList.remove( "Hidden" )
  }
  else NewW[1].classList.add( "Hidden" )

  if( event.target.value == "isosceles" ) {
    NewW[2].classList.remove( "Hidden" )
  }
  else NewW[2].classList.add( "Hidden" )
}
```

```css
.Hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral">
      <div class="Hidden">equilateral</div>
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle">
      <div class="Hidden">rectangle</div>
      <input type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">
      <div class="Hidden">isosceles</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` isn't being applied without `!important` because `display: none` in the style attribute in your html code has higher specificity than a class selector.
If you move `display: none` to your CSS file, your code should work without needing to use `!important`.

```js
let EquiConst = document.querySelector("#Eqi");
let RectConst = document.querySelector("#Rec");
let IsoConst = document.querySelector("#Iso");


let NewW = document.querySelectorAll(".Appear");



var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');


//use code from Azoof Ahmed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77956842/any-idea-about-why-my-background-color-is-not-workin/77957267#77957267
//but added just a simple feature on work in all my 3 elements
function handleChange(e) {
  if(e.target.value === 'equilateral') {
    NewW[0].classList.add("drop");
   
  } else {
    NewW[0].classList.remove("drop");
  }

  if(e.target.value === 'rectangle') {
    NewW[1].classList.add("drop");
  } else {
    NewW[1].classList.remove("drop");
  }               
  
  if(e.target.value === 'isosceles') {
    NewW[2].classList.add("drop");
  } else {
    NewW[2].classList.remove("drop");
  }
}

// trigger handler with all radio buttons
radioButtons.forEach(function(radioButton) {
    
        radioButton.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
    
    
});


//append child to my div appear for put some data in there

let sideEqui = document.createElement("input")
let child1 = NewW[0].appendChild(sideEqui);
```

```css
.Appear {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    transition: padding 0.5s;
}
.Appear.drop {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_content">
  <form>  
    <p>Choose the triangle type:</p>  
    <input class="App" id="Eqi" type="radio" name="Type" value="equilateral">Equilateral<br>  
    <div class="Appear"></div>
    <input class="App" id="Rec" type="radio" name="Type" value="rectangle"> Rectangle <br>  
    <div class="Appear"></div>
    <input class="App" id="Iso" type="radio" name="Type" value="isosceles">Isosceles <br>
    <div class="Appear" ></div>  
  </form>
</div>
```